# How can I make this code run better/faster (threading or multiprocessing)? And how can it be done?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a simple bot that logs into a site with cookies and checks for the price of an item and if that price meets the price I set it to, it purchases the item.

I am looking for ways to improve the speed of this bot. I really do not know if multiprocessing will make this bot faster in this case.

I am also looking for ways to make it more efficient if any.

```py
session = requests.session()
session.cookies["cookie"] = ""

log_in = session.get("https://www.example.com")
if log_in.status_code == 200:
    print("Logged In")
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid Cookie")

crsf_token = ""

def token():
    global crsf_token
    while True:
        crsf_token = re.search(r"<script>XsrfToken.setToken\('(.*?)'\);</script>", session.get('https://www.example.com').text).group(1)
        time.sleep(5)

def _cthread():
    while True:
        try:
            req = session.get(f"https://www.example.com/productID")
            if req.status_code == 429:
                time.sleep(5)
                continue

            for i in req.json()["data"]["Sellers"]:
                if i["Price"] <= 300:
                    session.post(f'https://www.example.com&expectedPrice={i["Price"]}&expectedSellerID={i["SellerId"]}&userAssetID={i["UserAssetId"]}', headers={"X-CSRF-TOKEN": crsf_token})
        except requests.urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError as E:
            pass


while True:
    threading.Thread(target=_cthread).start()
    threading.Thread(target=token).start()
```

I have not gotten much success with this but it does work right now.

Comment: I believe you are only executing one task. What do you suppose multithreading would be good for?

Comment: @BlueRineS: Might be helpful for the potentially large number of `POST` requests submitted in response to each `GET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not bandwidth constrained and the site won't shut down too many `POST`s submitted at once, you might gain a little from threading your `post` calls, changing:

```
        for i in req.json()["data"]["Sellers"]:
            if i["Price"] <= 300:
                session.post(f'https://www.example.com&expectedPrice={i["Price"]}&expectedSellerID={i["SellerId"]}&userAssetID={i["UserAssetId"]}', headers={"X-CSRF-TOKEN": crsf_token})
```

to:

```
        allposts = [f'https://www.example.com&expectedPrice={i["Price"]}&expectedSellerID={i["SellerId"]}&userAssetID={i["UserAssetId"]}'
                    for i in req.json()["data"]["Sellers"] if i["Price"] <= 300]
        if allposts:
            with Pool() as pool:
                pool.map(partial(session.post, headers={"X-CSRF-TOKEN": crsf_token}), allposts)
```

adding the following imports to the top of your file:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # Gets thread based worker Pool class
from functools import partial           # Lets you bind headers up front so you only need to pass URL to post
```

To avoid excessive thread spawning, you might create the `pool` outside the loop in that function, rather than creating it on demand only when `allposts` is non-empty.

I'd also recommend removing the `while True:` from the top level of your code; `token` and `_cthread` are already both infinite loops, so having both loops means spawning an infinite number of threads, each of which runs forever, when you really only need two persistent threads.

Comment: Thank you for the great response! Could you show me how to create the multiprocessing pool outside of the loop? I removed the `while True:` from the two functions. But definitely the cpu usage is very high

Comment: @EdwinTan: You don't want to remove it from the functions, you want to remove it from the top level (there is no reason to have multiple threads trying to `GET` at the same time). Creating it outside the loop is the same as inside the loop, just move the `with Pool() as pool:` outside the `while` and indent the `while` and its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove `while True` from functions `token()` & `_cthread()`

Comment: Why? I think it's better to remove while True from the main module instead, as the thread ought to be started only once..

Comment: @BlueRineS that would not be helpfull, he'll end up with one thread working, while Rk003's solution works because, it will stop endless creation of threads that almost never stop.

Comment: @a-sam: Removing it from the functions means spawning infinite threads at top level; odds are the thread spawning will race faster than the network requests, so the program will crash when it runs out of threads. You only need the two top level threads, each of which can run forever, without spawning new threads that are never cleaned.

Comment: OP said that `I am looking for ways to improve the speed of this bot` so I think this is better way.